# Deferrable document.write

Tags: javascript, onload, domdocument, document.write

alot of web advertising providers use the old document.write method, in my case AdTech.
Is it possible to overwrite the document.write method to defer after the onload event?

Comment: To what end? Also, can you use jQuery?

Answer (score 3):

How about using either

- writecapture (https://github.com/iamnoah/writeCapture) an utility to assist the Ajax loading of HTML containing script tags that use document.write or
- PostsScribe (https://github.com/krux/postscribe/) which lets you deliver a synchronous ad asynchronously without modifying the ad code.

Answer (score 0):

Moving all your scripts to the bottom of the page (before >/body<) with advert scripts absolutely last and not using domReady at all (don't need it if your scripts are put in after all HTML elements) will do the same thing. In fact, it might be possible that defering document.write calls can even ruin the entire page depending on how aweful the advert code is.

Comment: Yes, right now I'm pushing out all the adcode at bottom of the page, and moving them to their respective container elements, but it's very slow :\

Answer (score 0):

you can output a

```
document.old_write=document.write;
window._bufferedText='';
document.write=function(text) {
    window._bufferedText+=text;
}
//now let all the document.write go here
document.write('<h1>');
document.write('Hello World!');
document.write('</h1>');
//alert(window._bufferedText);
//end document.write methods
document.write=document.old_write;
document.write('<div id="deferred-write-placeholder"></div>');

window.onload=function() {
    document.getElementById('deferred-write-placeholder').innerHTML=window._bufferedText;
    delete window._bufferedText;
}
```

Notes:

- you can rewrite something more complex to handle all instances of `document.write` code chunks.
- you should replace `window.onload` with your javascript framework specific onload handler.

Comment: It's a step in the right direction, but the adcode can contain several document.write methods that again write out a script that uses document.write.

Comment: @supermads i think that this might actually work in that case too. Ad companies can't document write after the document has been closed and the onload callback has occurred (otherwise it would override the page with a new load). A method like the one above should work in theory.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually support script injection the correct way by intercepting calls to document.write as follows. The trick is to create a "middleman" function which checks inputs to document.write, and if it's a script tag being injected, load it correctly into the DOM instead:

```
document.writeText = document.write;

document.write = function(parameter) {
    if (!parameter) return; 
    var scriptPattern = /<script.*?src=['|"](.*?)['|"]/;
    if (scriptPattern.test(parameter)) {
        var srcAttribute = scriptPattern.exec(parameter)[1];
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = srcAttribute;
        document.head.appendChild(script); 
    }
    else {
        document.writeText(parameter);
    }   
};
```

Obviously this can be condensed down a bit further, but the variable names are included for clarity. If you like, you can follow up by using async and defer on the script tag loading the third-party library itself, making sure to test for correctness after such a change.

[Source](https://digitalrumpus.wordpress.com/2017/01/18/a-tiny-cross-browser-script-to-intercept-third-party-javascript-injection-via-document-write/)